# How to make expansion on dynamic column datatable

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I have a problem, I need to make an expansion row so I did something like:

```
<q-table
  :title="title"
  :data="driverTable.data"
  :columns="driverTable.columns"
  :visible-columns="driverTable.visibleCols"
  row-key="objectId"
  :loading="driverTable.loading"
  :filter="driverTable.filter"
>
  <template
    v-slot:body-cell-expandingrow="cellProperties"
  >
    <q-td 
      auto-width 
      :props="cellProperties"
    >
      <q-btn 
        size="sm" 
        color="accent" 
        round 
        dense 
        @click="cellProperties.expand = !cellProperties.expand" 
        :icon="cellProperties.expand ? 'remove' : 'add'" 
      />
    </q-td>
    <q-tr
      v-show="cellProperties.expand"
      :props="cellProperties"
    >
      <q-td
        colspan="100%"
      >
        <div
          class="text-left"
        >
          This is expand slot for row above: {{ cellProperties.row.name }}.
        </div>
      </q-td>
    </q-tr>
  </template>
    ...

data() {
  return {
    driverTable: {
      filter: '',
      loading: false,
      columns: [
        {
          name: 'objectId',
          field: row => row.objectId,
          format: val => '',
        },
        {
          name: 'name',
          label: 'Nom complete',
          align: 'left',
          field: row => row.name,
          format: val => `${val}`,
          sortable: true,
          classes: 'ellipsis',
        },
        {
          name: 'phone',
          required: true,
          label: 'Téléphone',
          field: row => row.phone,
          format: val => `${val}`,
        },
        {
          name: 'position',
          required: true,
          label: 'Position Actuelle',
          field: row => `${row.latitude}, ${row.longitude}`,
          format: val => `${val}`,
        },
        {
          name: 'carName',
          required: true,
          label: 'Voiture',
          field: row => row.carName,
          format: val => `${val}`,
          sortable: true,
        },
        {
          name: 'carSerie',
          required: true,
          label: 'Série',
          field: row => row.carSerie,
          format: val => `${val}`,
        },
        {
          name: 'carRef',
          required: true,
          label: 'Référence',
          field: row => row.carRef,
          format: val => `${val}`,
        },
        {
          name: 'carImage',
          required: true,
          label: 'Image',
          field: row => row.carImage,
          align: 'center',
          format: val => `${val}`,
        } 
      ],
      data: []
```

Just like quasar documentation but it display the expanding row just like another td on the table.

I know that the problem is when I make the td of btn with the row but as U see I dont use on my html any element jsut q-table to display the data table.

here is the result:
[image]

Comment: plz refer the documentation https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#Expanding-rows. I don't think you can use expansion item in body-cell slot you can implement in body slot.